# Boost::Process linker error in combination with boost::process::posix::use_vfork

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-process

I am toying around with `Boost::Process` (1.64.0), using GCC 7.1.1, trying to force the use of `vfork()` when forking a process. I am greeted by a linker error for the following program:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

namespace bp = ::boost::process;

int main(void)
{
  bp::child c("ls", bp::posix::use_vfork);
  c.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Using:

```
g++ use_vfork.cpp
```

The linker error generated is as follows

> In function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor >, boost::fusion::filter_view&, boost::process::detail::posix::use_vfork_ const&> const, boost::process::detail::is_initializer > > > >::operator()()':
>   spawn_simple.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7process6detail5posix8executorINS_6fusion10joint_viewINS4_5tupleIJNS2_12exe_cmd_initIcEEEEENS4_11filter_viewIKNS6_IJRA6_KcRNS2_8null_outILi1ELin1EEERKNS2_10use_vfork_EEEENS1_14is_initializerIN4mpl_3argILin1EEEEEEEEEEclEv[_ZN5boost7process6detail5posix8executorINS_6fusion10joint_viewINS4_5tupleIJNS2_12exe_cmd_initIcEEEEENS4_11filter_viewIKNS6_IJRA6_KcRNS2_8null_outILi1ELin1EEERKNS2_10use_vfork_EEEENS1_14is_initializerIN4mpl_3argILin1EEEEEEEEEEclEv]+0x31): undefined reference to `boost::process::detail::posix::executor >, boost::fusion::filter_view&, boost::process::detail::posix::use_vfork_ const&> const, boost::process::detail::is_initializer > > > >::invoke(mpl_::bool_, mpl_::bool_)'

As far as I know, Boost Process itself is header only, so why is it complaining about an undefined reference of `boost::process<...>::invoke()`?

I tried adding `-lboost_system` and `-lboost_iostreams`, but that does not solve the linker error.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13171

Comment: It's an error in the deduction of `BOOST_POSIX_HAS_VFORK`. The corresponding function is only included when that's defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a documentation bug/omission: `vfork` support is conditionally compiled-in:

```
#define BOOST_POSIX_HAS_VFORK 1
```

So this works:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>

namespace bp = ::boost::process;

int main(void)
{
    bp::child c("ls", bp::posix::use_vfork);
    c.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed builds fine. It throws some kind of `process_error` though. I will file a bug report.